# Column not found:1054 error even though the column is defined in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'vpc_order_info' in 'where clause' (SQL: `` select `sequa_transaction_id`
>   as `vpc_transaction_no`, `merchant_order_id` as `vpc_order_info`,
>   `date_created` as `yesterday`, `card_number` as `vpc_Card`, `amount`
>   as `vpc_Amount`, `authorization_code` as `vpc_authorizeId` from
>   `ipg_sentry_response` where `merchant_id` = 12136901 and
>   `vpc_order_info` like %-% and `response_code` = 1 and `date_created`
>   between 2016-03-22 and 2016-09-31) ``

I am getting this error message though I have defined the column as given below.

```
$col = array("sequa_transaction_id as vpc_transaction_no","merchant_order_id as vpc_order_info","date_created as yesterday","card_number as vpc_Card", "amount as vpc_Amount","authorization_code as vpc_authorizeId");

     $records = DB::table('ipg_sentry_response')->select($col)
     ->where('merchant_id', '=', $vpc_Merchant)
             ->where('vpc_order_info' ,'like', "%-%")            
     ->where('response_code', '=', '1')
     ->whereBetween('date_created', array($date,$date2))
     //->whereBetween('date_created', array($date,$date2))
     ->get();
```

Can anyone please help me with it? I am using Laravel version 5.2.

Comment: `Unknown column 'vpc_order_info'` means didnt defined in your table

Comment: Ensure 'merchant_order_id' exists in the table. check spellings

Answer (score 1):

The **column alias** is defined but it is not available to be used in `where` caluse yet. You can use `alias` in `group`, `order`... you need to use the column name instead of the alias. Try -

```
 $col = array("sequa_transaction_id as vpc_transaction_no",
        "merchant_order_id as vpc_order_info","date_created as yesterday",
        "card_number as vpc_Card", "amount as vpc_Amount",
        "authorization_code as vpc_authorizeId");

 $records = DB::table('ipg_sentry_response')->select($col)
 ->where('merchant_id', '=', $vpc_Merchant)
 ->where('merchant_order_id' ,'like', "%-%")            
 ->where('response_code', '=', '1')
 ->whereBetween('date_created', array($date,$date2))
 ->get();
```

> You can only use column aliases in **GROUP BY**, **ORDER BY**, or **HAVING** clauses. Standard SQL doesn't allow you to refer to a column alias in a **WHERE** clause.

Answer (score 0):

As what stated by the answer above mine, the WHERE clause doesn't accept aliases. Furthermore, you may also use the GROUP BY - HAVING methods (https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)